# C++ shared_ptr vs. unique_ptr for resource management

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, resourcemanager

I've been mulling over use of `unique_ptr` vs `shared_ptr` vs `own_solution`.  I've discounted the latter as I'll almost certainly get it wrong, but I have a problem with both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` in that neither captures precisely what I want.  I want to create a resource manager which explicitly owns a resource, however I'd like the resource manager to also hand out references to the resource.

If I use `unique_ptr` in the resource manager and hand out raw pointers there's the possibility they could escape elsewhere (though this would be against the class "contract" I suppose).  If I use `shared_ptr` and hand out `weak_ptr`, there's nothing stopping a caller from converting the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` and storing that, thereby potentially creating a cycle or worse, a resource living beyond the lifetime of the resource manager.  So I suppose what I'm looking for is a deferencable `weak_ptr` that cannot be converted into a `shared_ptr`.

Or am I just looking to enforce the contract with some strongly worded comments in the code?

Thanks for any thoughts you might have on this.

Comment: Any pointer could "escape" just as easily as a raw pointer so I don't see how that's much of a con wrt raw pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smart pointers like `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are a good tools when you have *owning* pointers.
But for non-owning pointers, i.e. *observing pointers*, using a raw pointer is just fine.

In your design, I think the resource manager is the only "owner" of the resources, so you could simply have some form of smart pointer *inside* the resource manager. For example, the resource manager can have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Resource>>` as a data member, or even a simpler `std::vector<Resource>` if your `Resource` class is designed to be correctly storable in a `std::vector`.

Then, the resource manager can give to the outside just non-owning observing pointers, and raw pointers (or C++ references) are fine for this case.

Of course, it's important that the lifetime of the resource manager exceeds that of the "resource clients".

Answer (score 9):

In the end, you cannot force anyone to listen. Ask at microsoft, apple or any open source library developer, they all know that song. A comment in the right words and places is your best bet.

**Avoid creating your own smart pointer class, it hinders composition and reduces readability. As a last resort, try looking in boost, or any framework your code already has to work with.**

If you have non-owners, they are either electable for holding `weak_ptr`s or (if it is guaranteed to stay valid for the duration) raw pointers.
If you use `shared_ptr`s internally (why should you), best provide `weak_ptr` and raw pointers.

All those smart pointers explicitly denote an ownership policy. Raw pointers denote none or non-owning.

- `auto_ptr`: Do not use, deprecated with too many traps even for the wary.
- `unique_ptr`: Sole ownership.
- `shared_ptr`: Shared ownership
- `weak_ptr`: No ownership, might get deleted behind your back.
- raw pointer

  - Explicitly no ownership with guaranteed bigger lifetime
  - or manual ownership management.

Comment: "Avoid creating your own smart pointer class": C++ STD is not a complete set of solutions for everything. If you want something for a special application, write it and use it. In particular C++ is a language which provides you that freedom compared to Java or C#. Just my 5 cents.

Comment: @Danvil: That's why it is only avoid, with a first fallback to common/already used frameworks. Too often the user will as first order of business evade your smart-poiter class, if it does not fit with other libraries he is using. And he will resent having to jump through those hoops.

Answer (score 3):

> So I suppose what I'm looking for is a deferencable weak_ptr that
>   cannot be converted into a shared_ptr.

You could hand out your one little helper class:

```
template<typename T>
class NonConvertibleWeakPtr
{
public:
   NonConvertibleWeakPtr(const std::shared_ptr<T>& p) : p_(p) {}
   ... // other constructors / assignment operators
   bool expired() const { return p_.expired(); }
   T* operator->() const { return get(); }
   T& operator*() const { return *get(); }
private:
   T* get() const { return p_.lock().get(); }
private:
   std::weak_ptr<T> p_;
};
```

This is slightly better than a raw pointer, because you can check if your pointer is still valid.

Example usage:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp = std::make_shared<int>(5);
{
    NonConvertibleWeakPtr<int> wp(sp);
    if(!wp.expired()) {
        std::cout << *wp << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However a user can still misuse it for example with `std::shared_ptr<T> blah(&(*wp));`, but it takes a bit more criminal energy.